# Objective-C block change global variable

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

```
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    self.pageIndex++;
});
```

or

```
__weak someController *weakSelf = self;
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    weakSelf.pageIndex++;
});
```

I am so confused. Which is right? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dispatch_after does not store the block in a way that is owned by 'self', so there's no risk of retain cycles here.

Given that, the question becomes what do you want to have happen? If self should be kept alive to make sure it can have its pageIndex incremented, use a strong reference. If the index should only be incremented if self is otherwise still alive, use a weak reference.

(Edit): also, there's no global variables involved here. You may want to read up on the difference between global, local, and instance variables.

Comment: Thank you, sir. It's very helpful, I got it.